# Why the default Controller implementation sends crashes with internal error?

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

I generated controller under `rest-api` grails app profile. Nothing is changed in controller, just some println calls added.

For call `curl -X PUT -d name=petr2 -d phone=338 localhost:8080/TSCell/3` I have `{"message":"Internal server error","error":500}` response. In debug I can see, that error occured after final `respond TSCell, [status: OK, view:"show"]` call.

Code for update method:

```
@Transactional
def update(TSCell tSCell) {
    println "in update method"
    if (tSCell == null) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        render status: NOT_FOUND
        return
    }

    if (tSCell.hasErrors()) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        respond tSCell.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    tSCell.save flush:true

    respond tSCell, [status: OK, view:"show"]
}
```

And stack trace

```
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [PUT] /TSCell/3
Model variable [TSCell] of with value [class zcrm.api.TSCell] type [java.lang.Class] is not of the correct type [zcrm.api.TSCell]. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: grails.views.ViewRenderException: Error rendering view: Model variable [TSCell] of with value [class zcrm.api.TSCell] type [java.lang.Class] is not of the correct type [zcrm.api.TSCell]
    at grails.views.AbstractWritableScript.writeTo(AbstractWritableScript.groovy:33)
    at grails.views.mvc.GenericGroovyTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(GenericGroovyTemplateView.groovy:71)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at grails.views.mvc.renderer.DefaultViewRenderer.render(DefaultViewRenderer.groovy:105)
    at grails.artefact.controller.RestResponder$Trait$Helper.internalRespond(RestResponder.groovy:188)
    at grails.artefact.controller.RestResponder$Trait$Helper.respond(RestResponder.groovy:98)
    at zcrm.api.TSCellController$$EQ0icN2W.$tt__update(TSCellController.groovy:64)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Model variable [TSCell] of with value [class zcrm.api.TSCell] type [java.lang.Class] is not of the correct type [zcrm.api.TSCell]
        at grails.views.WritableScriptTemplate.make(WritableScriptTemplate.groovy:138)
    at grails.plugin.json.view.api.internal.DefaultGrailsJsonViewHelper.prepareWritable(DefaultGrailsJsonViewHelper.groovy:736)
    at grails.plugin.json.view.api.internal.DefaultGrailsJsonViewHelper$7.writeTo(DefaultGrailsJsonViewHelper.groovy:713)
    at grails.plugin.json.view.JsonViewTemplate.json(JsonViewTemplate.groovy:126)
    at grails.plugin.json.view.JsonViewTemplate.json(JsonViewTemplate.groovy:149)
    at zcrm_api_TSCell_show_gson.run(zcrm_api_TSCell_show_gson:7)
    at grails.plugin.json.view.JsonViewTemplate.doWrite(JsonViewTemplate.groovy:35)
    at grails.views.AbstractWritableScript.writeTo(AbstractWritableScript.groovy:30)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That code shouldn't compile, but Groovy is too 'helpful' sometimes and allowed it through. You named an instance variable the same as its class, `TSCell`, and this turns out to be an interesting block of code to see how Groovy handles disambiguation between instance and static method calls.

For the first line, since you have `TSCell TSCell` it's possible for the compiler to know that the one on the left is the class name and the one on the right is an instance variable, since there's no other valid interpretation of those tokens.

In the third line it's not as clear whether the class or instance variable is being checked for null, but I tried this out locally and it's the instance variable.

`TSCell.hasErrors()` could be interpreted as a static method call on the class or a call on the instance, but since that method isn't static, Groovy invokes it on the instance and it succeeds. The same logic has to be applied to the `save` call, but again since it's not a static method it's call on the instance and succeeds.

And then on the last line of the method, kaboom, your luck ran out after four successful calls. There are a few overloads of the `respond` method and you end up calling `respond(Object, Map)`, and that's valid for either `TSCell` the class, or `TSCell` the instance of the `TSCell` class. Groovy picked the one that wasn't what you intended and the one that isn't supported inside the `respond` method.

Groovy shares Java's variable and class naming conventions, i.e. class names start with an uppercase letter and instance variable names start with a lowercase letter. It's one thing to just tell people that this is a good approach, but an example like this makes it a lot more obvious why it's a bad idea to use uppercase instance variable names (you should be able to look at the variable and not need to see its declaration to know if it's a class or var name) and why it's even worse to use the same name as the class.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but there was code where I named variable like tsCell , but no luck. However .. I should check out the last one  appearance. Is it should be the variable name , isn't it?

Comment: " Is it should be the variable name , isn't it?" - Yes.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, It's good answer, but it's not the resolution for error. I've  just checked code. Code snippet in question updated.

Comment: @Juriy That doesn't make sense to me.  If you can provide a sample app which demonstrates that behavior, file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and provide a link that app and we can investigate.

Answer (score 1):

This error is probably caused because you named parameter with same name as class name.

I would suggest that you change name of the variable to lowercase (this is groovy and java naming convention).

```
def update(TSCell tsCell) { //you can also just write tsCell without type
    println "in update method"
    if (tsCell == null) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        render status: NOT_FOUND
        return
    }

    if (tsCell.hasErrors()) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        respond tsCell.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    tsCell.save flush:true

    respond tsCell, [status: OK, view:"show"]
}
```

Comment: @Juriy but surely Randall's suggestion would change the error message, you have some obvious issues in your code above.  I would suggest you add a println in the bit if (tsCell.hasErrors()) { println "errors are ${tsCell.errors}"    to see if you have some errors in the data collected you can also do println params and compare with what domainClass is expecting aka essential vs what you have in params

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the call `curl`. As [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#contentNegotiation) says `Grails has built in support for Content negotiation using either the HTTP Accept header, an explicit format request parameter or the extension of a mapped URI.`

So the adding `-H "Accept: application/xml"` to the above `curl` call resolved the issue.